How to compare the acidity by a calculation?

We have two solutions of weak acid $\ce{HA}$ and $\ce{HB}$ with equal volume and equal $\mathrm{pH}$. Let the temperature be fixed and the dissociation constants of $\ce{HA}$ and $\ce{HB}$ be $K_1$ and $K_2$, where $K_1>K_2$. Now we add the same volume of water into each solution. Determine which solution has the greater $\mathrm{pH}$ now.

Here is a tricky but not rigorous answer. Since $\ce{HA}$ is a stronger acid than $\ce{HB}$ ($K_1>K_2$), just let $\ce{HA}$ be a strong acid. Then after dilution, $n\left(\ce{H+}\right)$ in the $\ce{HA}$ solution does not change, because all the $\ce{HA}$ molecules have ionized; $n\left(\ce{H+}\right)$ in the $\ce{HB}$ solution increases, because dilution promotes ionization for weak acids. Hence, $c\left(\ce{H+}\right)$ in the $\ce{HA}$ solution is less than in the $\ce{HB}$ solution, meaning that the $\mathrm{pH}$ in the $\ce{HA}$ solution is greater.
Anyhow, the above argument is not rigorous. So I want a calculation based method to show that the $\mathrm{pH}$ in the $\ce{HA}$ solution is greater. I think we need to use
$$K_1=\frac{c\left(\ce{H+}\right)c\left(\ce{A-}\right)}{c(\ce{HA})},\quad K_2=\frac{c\left(\ce{H+}\right)c\left(\ce{B-}\right)}{c(\ce{HB})},$$
but I cannot complete it.

Note. $c(~)$ and $n(~)$ mean concentration and amount of substance respectively.

Are the initial concentrations of HA and HB equal? Or maybe they are not equal, but adjusted so as to have equal pH? (These would be two different problems with different answers.) Anyhow, some sort of condition is necessary. Short of that, we don't have enough data.

I'd guess the problem does not make any sense if they don't have the same initial pH. But it's still poorly worded (including the phrase "greater pH" which is ambiguous).

@BuckThorn Yes, the initial $\mathrm{pH}$ are the same. And what is wrong with "greater $\mathrm{pH}$"?

pH is a numerical scale in which the value decreases with increasing hydronium concentration. In the question, does "greater pH" mean more basic?

I don't understand "more basic". I learned that $\mathrm{pH}=-\lg c\left(\ce{H+}\right)$, so it is a number. For an acid, I the larger the $\mathrm{pH}$, the weaker its acidity. @BuckThorn

@BuckThorn I am surprised that you ask. As greater than or GT or ">" are standard logical binary operators, pH1 greater than pH2 means pH1 > pH2.  The only confusion can be of there are compared the  final solutions, or a final and initial one. Vinegar being more basic than car battery acid is technically correct, otherwise funny.

True enough. I guess I was confused about the question being potentially confusing.

At conditions $c \gg [\ce{H+}] \gg [\ce{OH-}]$,
$$K_\text{a} \approx \frac{[\ce{H+}]^2}{c} \tag{1}$$
$$\text{pH} \approx 0.5(\text{p}K_\text{a} - \log{c})\tag{2}$$
So the resulting $\text{pH}$ would stay approximately the same for both solutions.
If the condition $c \gg [\ce{H+}]$ is not valid and significant portion of the acid is dissociated, the above equation is not valid  and $\text{pH}$ would be greater. As both fraction terms get smaller.
$$K_\text{a} \approx \frac{[\ce{H+}]^2}{c - [\ce{H+}]}\tag{3}$$
$$[\ce{H+}]^2 + K_\text{a} [\ce{H+}] - K_\text{a}c =0\tag{4}$$
$$[\ce{H+}]= \frac{-K_\text{a} + \sqrt{ K_\text{a}^2 + 4K_\text{a}c}}{2}  \tag{5} $$
$$c = \frac{[\ce{H+}]^2}{ K_\text{a}}  + [\ce{H+}]\tag{6} $$
If there in involved parameter $a$ representing dilution as $c_\text{new}=a \cdot c$, $K = K_\text{a}$ and $H = [\ce{H+}]$, then:
$$a(\frac{H^2}{K} + H) = \frac{H^2_\text{new}}{K} + H_\text{new}\tag{7}$$
$$H^2_\text{new} + H_\text{new}K - a(H^2 + HK) = 0\tag{8}$$
$$H_\text{new} = \frac{-K + \sqrt{K^2 +4a(H^2 + HK)}}{2}\tag{9}$$
If all is computed for formic and acetic acids, initial pH 4 and dilution 10 times:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Parameter} & \text{Formic acid} & \text{Acetic acid} \\
\hline
\text{pKa} & 3.75 & 4.75 \\
\text{Ka} & 1.778 \times 10^{-4} & 1.778 \times 10^{-5} \\
\text{pH} & 4 & 4 \\
\text{[H+]} & 1.000 \times 10^{-4} & 1.000 \times 10^{-4} \\
\text{c} & 1.562 \times 10^{-4} & 6.623 \times 10^{-4} \\
\text{a} & 0.1 & 0.1 \\
\text{[H+]$_{\text{new}}$} & 1.445 \times 10^{-5} & 2.656 \times 10^{-5} \\
\text{pH$_{\text{new}}$} & 4.84 & 4.58 \\
\hline
\end{array}
Dilution ten times means for acids with very low dissociation $\text{pH}$ increase by 0.5 what is  approximately true for
$$\text{pH} \lt \text{p}K_\text{a} -2\tag{7}$$
This number converges for full dissociation to 1.0 when
$$\text{pH} \gt \text{p}K_\text{a} + 2\tag{8}$$
It means that if the solutions of two acids have initially the same pH, then after dilution the solution of the stronger acid would have the greater $\text{pH}$ than the weaker one.
This again would need correction for water auto dissociation at very high dilutions when $[\ce{H+}] \gg [\ce{OH-}]$ is  not valid. Or due correction to activities instead of concentrations. But the $\text{pH}$ order would remain.

I can understand that $[\ce{H+}]= \frac{-K_\text{a} + \sqrt{ K_\text{a}^2 + 4K_\text{a}c}}{2}$, but how does this help determine my how much $[\ce{H+}]$ changes? I think perhaps we need to compute derivatives?

I once had them there, as dC/d[H+] and than inverted. d[H+]/dc=Ka/(2[H+] + Ka). Then I deleted it for some reason.

One way is to calculate c from from pH and Ka, diluting it and calculate pH back. will do when back at computer.
